# Using vim to transform indented dirlist to full paths

Tags: regex, vim

I have inherited a set of files with indented directory listings, like this:

```
DirA/
  DirA1/
  DirA2/
    DirA2.1/
  DirA3/
DirB/
DirC/
  DirC1/
    DirC1.1/
      DirC1.1.1/
    DirC1.2/
```

For a migration to new code and a new structure I need to change this to a full path on each line.

```
DirA/
DirA/DirA1/
DirA/DirA2/
DirA/DirA2/DirA2.1/
DirA/DirA3/
DirB/
DirC/
DirC/DirC1/
DirC/DirC1/DirC1.1/
DirC/DirC1/DirC1.1/DirC1.1.1/
DirC/DirC1/DirC1.2/
```

I'd prefer to use `vim` for this (if only to increase my vim fuu), but I haven't yet found out how to do this (using regexes, registers and/or macros?). Could anyone please give me some pointers? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I just test my answer with online tools, it was working. if you have any problems, let us know!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming an indent of width of 2 spaces:

```
:%s#^\s\+#\=join(split(getline(line('.')-1),'/')[:strlen(submatch(0))/2-1],'/').'/'
```

#### Overview

The idea is to get the previous line (`getline(line('.')-1)`) and split the line into directories. Then do a substitution on the leading spaces and replacing with the sublist of list of directories from the previous line according the the indent level, `strlen(submatch(0))/2-1`.

#### Glory of details

- `%s#^\s\+#{replacement}` - do a substitution on lines staring with spaces
- `\={expr}` will yield the result of `{expr}` as the replacement for the spaces - this is called a sub-replace-expression
- `getline(line('.')-1)` - get the previous line
- `split(getline(line('.')-1), '/')` - split up the previous lines into directory segments
- `lst[{start}:{end}]` - create a sublist from list, `lst`, starting from `{start}` and ending at index `{end}`.
- `lst[:{end}]` - assume start of list. e.g `[0,1,2][:1]` yields `[0,1]`
- `submatch(0)` - inside a sub-replace-expression `submatch({n}` will get the capture group number, `{n}`
- `submatch(0)` will yield the entire matching pattern of the substitution. aka `\0` or `&` in a normal substitution
- `strlen(submatch(0))/2` will get the current line's indention level
- `strlen(submatch(0))/2-1` will be 1 indention level less. aka. the part of the directory structure that the current line and the line above have in common
- `join({lst}, {glue})` - join a list together as a string with `{glue}` as the separator between list items
- Add a `/` at the end as it got taken out by `split()`
- It is important to know that Vim does the substitution line by line starting from the top (as noted by @Lieven Keersmaekers). This means we can use the previous line to get the common ancestors

For more help see:

```
:h :s
:h sub-replace-expression
:h getline()
:h line()
:h join()
:h sublist
:h strlen()
:h split()
```

Comment: Oh.my.god.
We really need something like excel's functionality to evaluate a formula step by step. I can figure out most of it but trying to apply it on top of my head to a line get's me a headache.

Comment: You  might want to add that this works because vim replaces line by line so you have *(and need)* the replaced line - 1 for your current line *(I'm hoping I make myself clear)*. The `[:<number>]` notation returning a subset of a list might be worth mentioning too. I have learned a lot from your oneliner *(again)*, tx.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I have converted this to just a substitution and added a description

Comment: I actually liked the global command because of the extra things it taught me but vimwise, shorter *is* better. This one goes in my vimtips!

Comment: Wow! I am reasonably well-versed in regexes, but this I wouldn't have thought of. Thanks for the solution and the very thorough explanation. It works like a charm. It seems I need to read up on the standard functions vim offers, because I am missing out on a lot. Submatch() was unknown to me. Just one question left.

Comment: At first I would have thought that getline(line('.')-1) would generate an error on the first line, but after reading the help I see it will result in an empty string. All other processing on this empty string just results in another empty string. Am I correct in that supposition? Thanks again for teaching me more about vim!

Comment: @TheoTrui, `getline(line('.')-1)` will yield an empty string. You can test this via `:echo getline(0)`. I avoid this issue by using `^\s\+` for the pattern instead of `^\s*`. This ensures there will always be a parent directory.

Comment: Thanks again. I learned some new things about vim through this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this regex:

```
/^(.+\/)((\r?\n(\s\s){1,}\S+){0,})\r?\n\s\s(\S+)/gm
```

And replacing by one of these:

```
$1$2\n$1$5
$1$2\r\n$1$5
```

(if you need `\n` line breaks or `\r\n`)

Demo : https://regex101.com/r/iwXMot/2

How works:

- capture first Directory (has no `\s` before)
- capture all lines till line has `\s\s` while next one has no `\s` at the beginning. it is last sub directory.
- add parent directory to last subdirectory and remove `\s\s`
- continue this loop!
- for next steps, change **the last** `\s\s` to `\s{4}` and next one `\s{6}` and ...

I don't know `vim`, but hope this regex pattern helps!

Comment: OP is trying to **change** text from file 1 to file 2 by including parent directories to each subdirectory.

Comment: I was thinking this text is input and needs to change to new text @Meninx-メネンックス

Comment: So you are aware that your solution doesn't answer the OP's question !

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have used Peter's oneliner since that was more fun to learn and it is a one-step solution to the problem I was facing. But just like in perl vim has more than one way to do things.